# wso2 identity server ldap browsing

Tags: ldap, wso2

I'm trying to browse the WSO2 user store ldap using `ldapsearch` or Apache LDAP browser and am unable to connect. Here is the Ldapsearch error

```
C:\OpenLDAP\bin>ldapsearch.exe -h localhost -p 10390 -b "uid=admin,ou=system"

SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password: admin
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: INVALID_CREDENTIALS: DIGEST-MD5: digest response format violation. Mismatched URI: ldap/; expecting : ldap/localhost
```

I'm using default ldap of WSO2 installed on windows 7 laptop. Am I using the right port?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try (with default configuration | without setting port offset),

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w "admin"
```

If you are not sure about the port which embedded LDAP is starting you could check that with server start up logs (or the console). There should be a entry like following,

```
09:54:23,842 org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator  -  Initializing Directory Server with working directory /wso2is-4.7.0/repository/data/org.wso2.carbon.directory and port 10389
```

With the default configurations embedded LDAP start on port `10389`.

You could use `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` if you need any additional information to build the connetion for you LDAP browser.

Usually needed values are (for default configurations),

```
ConnectionURL : ldap://localhost:10389
ConnectionName : uid=admin,ou=system
ConnectionPassword : admin
```

---

UPDATE:

In most cased above command is used to validate some ldap query using the command line. Hence following example uses of ldap search commands will be useful.

1. Adding the search base to the query. This can be done with '-b' flag like following.

   `ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w "admin" -b "ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org"`
2. Adding the search filter to the query. This can be done adding filter criteria without any flags like follows,

   `ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w "admin" -b "ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org" "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=admin))"`

HTH,

DarRay